# Can we select database connections in c# based on different users who logins?

Tags: c#, sql, connection

I am setting up architecture for an application, where there is a **Master Database** where for each new client registered in the system will have its own **new database**.

What I have to do is when a client logins, the database should be fetched for that given credentials of client. And new connection string is to be added in a running application.

c#, .Net MVC, SQL Server 2017

Comment: make sure that the user DB has a predefined structure like dbo.[user name]DB and then you can build the connection string with [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Where are you storing the database name of the different client?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I am storing the databases on the same sql server.

Comment: What's the logic of identifying database name based on the client name?